# Is it ever not possible to split a joint density into its marginals?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

If I have a joint probability density $f(x,y)$, are there any regularity conditions that need to be met in order to allow $f(x,y) = f(y|x)f(x)$, or is this *always* possible? The statistics books I consulted state this as something obviously true without elaborating further.

> [[Abramovich & Ritov, p. 186]](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Statistical_Theory/PJ7NBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA186) Given the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ one can always obtain their *marginal* distributions. Thus, for the continuous case, if $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is the joint density of $X$ and $Y$, their marginal densities $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are $f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)dy$ and $f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y)dx$. Two random variables X and Y are called *independent* if their joint density is a product of the marginal densities $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_X(x) \cdot f_Y(y)$ ...

> [[Spanos, p. 139]](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Probability_Theory_and_Statistical_Infer/9nCiDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA139): It should come as no surprise to learn that from the joint distribution one can always recover the **marginal** (univariate) **distributions** of the individual random variables involved.

I just wondered if there's more to it.

And, a related question: could there be a situation where $f(x,y) = f(y|x)f(x)$ is possible, but $f(x,y) = f(x|y)f(y)$ is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is typically abused in Statistics, I write $f(x,y), f(x \mid y), f(x),$ etc. for the densities of $(X,Y), X \mid Y = y, X,$ etc. I assume all of these are continuous.

You start with $f(x,y).$ Given this, you construct $f(y) = \int dx\ f(x,y)$ and then $f(x \mid y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}.$ Note that if $f(x,y) = 0$ on the line $\{x\} \times \mathbf{R}$ then $f(y) = 0$ and reciprocally, if $f(y) = 0,$ then $f(x,y) = 0$ for all $x$ (since we are assuming $f$ is continuous). Then, by definition, $f(x,y) = f(y) f(x \mid y)$ (when  $f(x,y) = f(y) = 0,$ the value of $f(x \mid y)$ can be arbitrarily defined as any number). So, you are asking whether or not $f(x,y) = f(x \mid y) f(y);$ the answer is yes, always, by definition.

**Addendum:** the question as to *why* $f(x \mid y)$ is a density for $X \mid Y = y$ is somewhat difficult and usually out of scope in statistics books. It has to do with the definition of conditional expectation and regular conditional probabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It appears your addendum aims at the heart of my question. Are there any measure-theoretic subtleties, or are we in the realm of logic when defining conditional probabilities?

Comment: If you have enough mathematical maturity I'd recommend Resnick's book (A probability Path), Ash's (Real Analysis and Probability) or Breiman's (Probabiity) all of which have the conditional expectation definition. With enough theoretical tools, my addendum is actually not hard to prove but you do need measure-theory for that.

Comment: Thanks for the references. Most helpful was theorem 5.8.4 in Ash and its proof, referring back to the product measure theorem. While looking around further, I noticed that the more difficult problem seems to be the reverse of the factorization, i.e. going from given $p(x)$ and $p(y|x)$ to $p(x,y)$ (cf. [Gelman & Speed](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1993.tb01477.x)).

Comment: I think the paper you refer to tackled a different problem: given $f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_d)$ and $f(x_i \mid x_j),$ determine $f(x_1, \ldots, x_d).$ The problem you wrote "given $f(x)$ and $f(y \mid x)$, determine $f(x,y)$" is trivial and the solution is $f(x,y) = f(y \mid x) f(x).$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction. To me it seems the Gelman-Speed paper asks whether given conditional densities uniquely specify a joint density. My original question, on the other hand, asks the reverse: can a given joint density always be split into conditionals and/or marginals.

Comment: Another interesting problem is: given $f(x \mid y)$ and $f(y \mid x),$ determine $f(x,y).$ Anyway, __your__ problem is the trivial one: given $f(x,y),$ can we do $f(x,y) = f(x \mid y) f(y).$ As I already answered, "yes, always, by definition."

Comment: Thank you for the comments, this was a really helpful discussion. As I understand it now, we can always find marginals because marginalization means integration, and probabilities are integrable by construction (correct me if I'm wrong, please). Also, for the "given $f(x|y)$ and $f(y|x)$, determine $f(x,y)$" problem, are there any recent textbook treatments you would recommend?

Comment: So, the issue of the non-trivial problems (recover $f(x,y)$ given $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ or given $f(x \mid y),$ $f(y \mid x)$) is that they usually have infinitely many solutions. The main idea tends to be you assume $f(x,y)$ to be of some "family of distributions" (e.g. normal) and you know the marginals, then you can recover the joint. I think I've read a few things about this in KDE (kernel density estimation) but they all assume normality of all variables and try to recover the joint distribution.